# How do I create a new page from my Wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress

In my wordpress plugin, I want to generate a page on the fly.

I could have the user create the page for me. But I would rather not have them do any steps. Just let them activate it and it works.

So I was wondering is there a way for me to do this, which maintains all the functionality within the plugin.

My initial idea was to add a rewrite rule

add_rewrite_rule('my_page/$', 'wp-content/plugins/my_plugin/page.php', 'top');

Then in my plugin I can have a page.php. Which works well, but I cannot get the header/footer etc.

I am very new to wordpress, so chances are i am missing somethign obvious.

Comment: I don't get your point.. Could you explain a little better what you want to do?

Comment: i have update it, hopefully it makes more sense to readers!

Comment: Let me see if i understood. You have a plugin that needs some pages. And you want when you activate the plugin, automattically the page is created. I'm right?

Comment: exactly! My plugin does a custom search. This is done by over-riding the search form. My search form has an action="/new_page/". I need a new_page to exist.

Answer (score 4):

You could create a 404 page code snippet that does wp_insert_post() and then redirects the user to it.

Your theme's 404.php would look like this:

```
<?php
$post_id = wp_insert_post("post_title" => "my post title", "post_content" => "Lol");
header("location:" . get_permalink( $post_id ) );
die();
?>
```

Comment: To me, this seems like a bad hack. The 404 page is there for a reason and I don't think it's a great idea to override its purpose of informing users that a page can not be found. It seems like there ought to be a more standardized and documented way of doing this...

Comment: Oh, it's a terrible, terrible hack. But appropriate to the terrible question.